# How do I allow a user to select a configuration file when building my WiX installer?

Tags: windows-7, installation, wix

I'm using WiX XML to create an install package.

One of the things I'd like the user/installer to be able to do is select from one (and only one) of several config files (i.e., config1.txt, config2.txt, config3.txt) that would wind up in the same location after the install is done (i.e., the final file is config.txt).  How do I do this in WiX?

The manual install has the user copying the desired config file to the final location/file.  i.e., if the user wants to use config2.txt, he copies config2.txt to config.txt.  He runs the program.  Then later, if he needs to use config1.txt, he copies config1.txt to config.txt and runs the program.

Any idea how to do this in WiX?

Thanks in advance!

-Adeena

Comment: You can install the config files. During install you ask user to select the config. Then before `InstallFinalize` you schedule a custom action which will copy the config selected by user to config.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

I solve a similar problem using a CopyFile tag;

Somewhere I have a `<Directory>` containing the following components:

```
<Component Id="Config_6.txt" Guid="{}">
  <File Id="Config_6.txt" Name="Config_6.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\..\bin\Config_6.txt" />
</Component>
<Component Id="Config.txt" Guid="{}">
  <File Id="Config.txt" Name="Config_8.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\..\bin\Config.txt" />
</Component>
<Component Id="Config_7.txt" Guid="{}">
  <File Id="Config_7.txt" Name="Config_7.txt" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\..\bin\Config_7.txt" />
</Component>

<Component Id="R8_Config.txt" Guid="{}">
  <CreateFolder/>
  <CopyFile Id="R8_Config.txt" FileId="Config.txt" DestinationName="Config.txt"/>
</Component>
<Component Id="R7_Config.txt" Guid="{}">
  <CreateFolder/>
  <CopyFile Id="R7_Config.txt" FileId="Config_7.txt" DestinationName="Config.txt"/>
</Component>
<Component Id="R6_Config.txt" Guid="{}">
  <CreateFolder/>
  <CopyFile Id="R6_Config.txt" FileId="Config_6.txt" DestinationName="Config.txt"/>
</Component>
```

And in the Features part something like this:

```
<Feature Id="Config" Title="Config directory" Display="expand" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="Config">
  <Feature Id="Config8" Title="Config 8" Level="1" Description="Select only one  version!">
    <ComponentRef Id="R8_Config.txt"/>
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="Config7" Title="Config 7" Level="1002" Description="Select only one  version!">
    <ComponentRef Id="R7_Config.txt"/>
  </Feature>
  <Feature Id="Config6" Title="Config 6" Level="1004" Description="...">
    <ComponentRef Id="R6_Config.txt"/>
  </Feature>
</Feature>
```

To display the features, add a UIRef that contains `CustomizeDlg`, for example:

```
<UIRef Id="WixUI_FeatureTree" />
```

A disadvantage of this solution is that the user can select multiple config files. That will probably cause the last one to become the active one.

Comment: I think you can add a Combobox control on a dialog for user to select the required config. Depending on user selection, you set a property which is used to conditionally install the components or to change the values of those features.

Comment: Copying files like this leaves the original files where they are. You also can't add delete="yes" to the CopyFile element because if refers to a file by id. The only reason I know this is because I am stuck with the same problem and don't have a solution ! :(

Answer (score 1):

Is this a web app? Are these ini files or xml files or something else? I prefer application configuration to be done by the application itself after installation during first launch (if it is an exe file). An installation is about getting default settings and files in place, any custom configuration is beyond the scope of initial deployment in my opinion.

Wix provides a feature to update an xml file during installation, here is a sample: http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/lesson6.php#6.10 . This would allow you to write a specific config setting to the file if it is an XML file.

There is nothing stopping you from installing several flavors of the same config file in the same folder and allowing the user to manually switch between them. What values typically change if you switch the base file? One or many settings?

Comment: No, it's not a web app.  Yes, a user could manually change the config file - which is what is done now.  I'm just trying to make it easier - reduce the number of steps the user has to take.  I totally understand the point about doing this within the application, but that's currently not possible because I don't have access to modifying the app - I'm just making the install package.  (This is a hobby project, and team members time is limited - so I have to work with what I have to make the simplest install possible)

Comment: A little more background... it's an application that's being submitted for a contest - so it's not being distributed to the general public. Last year, there was some concern that the install was too complicated so I'm trying to simplify as much as possible.  It might not be possible to remove all the steps - and manually changing the config might have to stay.

Comment: And lastly... the config file is a text based file, not an XML file... <sigh>